# Scraping ASP page with Python and Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to python and Scrapy.

For my current project, I'm trying to make a scraper which can pass a query via POST method to a ASP page and parse a `<td>` value from the output page.

I've written the following code

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = ['https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Forth_Results.aspx']
        download_delay = 1.5

        scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
                'ContentPlaceHolder1_SmartSearch_smartSearch': 'TORRENT PHARMACEUTICALS LTD',
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$SmartSearch$hdnCode': 500420,
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hf_scripcode': 500420,
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidCurrentDate': '7/20/2020 12:00:00 AM',
                '__VIEWSTATE': response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
                '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': response.css('input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').extract.first(),
                '__EVENTVALIDATION': response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract.first()
            },
            callback=self.parse,
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        return response.css('tr.TTrow td[2] ::text').extract()
```

It is giving me following error:

> NameError: name 'response' is not defined

I want to run this scraper in a cronjob with the search field (ContentPlaceHolder1_SmartSearch_smartSearch) passed through a list of names.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to the response in the `start_requests`

If you move your code to the `parse` function, it should work:

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ['https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Forth_Results.aspx']
    download_delay = 1.5

    def parse(self, response):
        formdata = {
           'ContentPlaceHolder1_SmartSearch_smartSearch': 'TORRENT PHARMACEUTICALS LTD',
           'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$SmartSearch$hdnCode': "500420",
           'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hf_scripcode': "500420",
           'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidCurrentDate': '7/20/2020 12:00:00 AM',
           '__VIEWSTATE': response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
           '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': response.css('input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').extract_first(),
           '__EVENTVALIDATION': response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first()
        }

        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata=formdata,
            callback=self.parse_post,
        )

    def parse_post(self, response):
        data = ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your suggestion solved the previous problem, but the spider is still running with an error. It shows Spider Error Processing. Is there a way I can troubleshoot what part of it is causing the problem? Best Regards

Comment: If my answer solved your original issue, please mark as resolved. 
Concerning you other issue, scrapy should tell you what the issue is so you can solve it.
It seems like your issue is with the CSS selector. I'm not sure what you are trying to extract but you could do something like this in `parse_post` function: `data = response.css('.TTRow td').extract()` and then `return {'data': data}`